# How to convert {"key":"user_id"}, {"value":"123"} to {"user_id":"123"} in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am using Dictionary to build up key/value and need to stringify it for HTTP Post.  They problem is when I stringify the data using Cordova's JsonHelper, it displays the "key:" and "value:" then the actual key and value.  I want to remove these.

I am developing for Windows Phone 8.

This:

```
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data.Add("user_id", user_id);
data.Add("order_id", order_id);
data.Add("package_id", package_id);
data.Add("order_status", "0"); //0 is success
data.Add("platform", "windows");
String postData = WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON.JsonHelper.Serialize(data);
```

Outputs:

```
[{"Key":"user_id","Value":"33"},{"Key":"order_id","Value":"07dbda1d-f877-4be8-b2d9-dba1f4622054"},{"Key":"package_id","Value":"package4"},{"Key":"order_status","Value":"0"},{"Key":"platform","Value":"windows"}]
```

Comment: I haven't used that serializer, but would using an anonymous object like this work? `var data = new { user_id = user_id, order_id = order_id, package_id = package_id, order_status = "0", platform = "windows" };` and serialize that `data` object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in Json serializer ([JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx))

```
string postData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
```

or [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (Which supports *Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8*)

```
string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Output would be:

```
{
  "user_id": "1",
  "order_id": "100",
  "package_id": "200",
  "order_status": "0",
  "platform": "windows"
}
```